# M-x pyvenv-activate, which folder to be pointed out in emacs?

Tags: python, emacs

Trying to convince jedi.el to start coperating me in GNU Emacs 24.5 with my Python 3.4 demystifying adventure.
Have downloaded all requirements (Python-environment.el, deferred.el were automatically installed) as stated in their requirement section (http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/latest/#install).

Further, as Jedi was looking for virtualenv, downloaded pyvenv.el, which again wanted to know the directory address, assuming it wants the address of some virtualenv created virtual environment through cmd.exe with command-
    c:\Python34\python -m pyvenv akkenv
which created a directory (akkenv)at -
    C:\Windows\System32

Installed Pyvenv.el through M-x list-package
tried to activate it through
    Mx pyvenv-activate
showed him akkenv
however it seems he wants to go further deep down...where should I lead him to? My akkenv directory shows follwing folders -
    Include
    Lib
    Scripts
    pyvenv.cfg (which is not accessible when I am pointing towards it in minibuffer)

What am I supposed to do to make it working ? will appreciate your effort in providing me detailed help...

Comment: What do you mean by "he wants to go further deep down"?  Does it not work if you select the `akkenv` directory?  How does it not work?

Comment: Anyway, if your task is just to get Jedi running, pointing it to the `akkenv` base directory should be sufficient.

Comment: its not....saying wrong type argument: stringp, nill

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with the help of jorgenshaefer. Refer  [pyvenv-activate bug](https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/pyvenv/issues/31)